# Django popup error message on same email submit

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

am wondering how i can get a popup message to tell the user this email is already registerd.

I got this in my models.py and the unique=True is blocking same email signup all i need is some code to let the user know it already signed up how can i do this?

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class Subscriber(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return '%s' % self.email
```

Comment: My first idea is to use ajax call to a view (with login name argument) which will return a HttpResponse with a state. I will trigger the ajax call with e.g. $('').change(..). And you could have some green/red icon next to login input.

Comment: Please share the code of your view/form/template you are currently using.